# PHPMailer не выдает ошибок, но и не отправляет письма

Tags: php, вывод, email, phpmailer, формы

PHPMailer не выдает ошибок, но и не отправляет письма.

```
<?php 
require_once('./phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'email@yandex.ru';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom('email@yandex.ru'); 
$mail->addAddress('example@yandex.ru');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$title = "<h1>Новая заявка</h1>";
$date = date("d.m.y H:i");

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка от ' .$date;
$mail->Body = $title. '<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ' .$name. '</p><p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ' .$phone;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Ошибка';
} else {
    header('Location: thx.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: Так не надо делать, давать ответ в вопросе. Задайте сначла вопрос, в самом его низу отметьте "Ответить на собственный вопрос", и дать ответ. Почитайте [делитесь знаниями в виде вопросов и ответов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.74756630.507593272.1617306340-1984730472.1617306340).

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: Рад был помочь! Можете начать с  этого вопроса, он будет скорее всего закрыт и вы можете просто открыть новый вопрос. Забегая вперёд скажу, что задать хороший вопрос подчас гораздо сложнее, чем на него ответить.

Comment: Всё. Сделал. Ещё раз спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче говоря, ошибка была достаточно странной. Всё дело в smtp от Яндекса. Я пробовал разные порты и разные защитные протоколы (tls и ssl), но ничего не помогало.

**РЕШЕНИЕ: Вам нужно использовать gmail почту для отправки сообщений. По крайнее мере, мне это помогло. Все правильные настройки ниже (лучше просто скопипастить код, исправить в нем только почты и пароли и наслаждаться жизнью)**

Ссылка на скачивание той версии, что и у меня. Так как не факт, что более новые или более старые версии phpmailer будут работать с этим кодом: http://failzoma.ru/file/9f287a

Хорошо работает с гугловской почтой (gmail.com).

P.S.: этот код не работает (пока что, но я пытаюсь это исправить) на бесплатных хостингах (на платных не проверял, знатоки могут ответить). На опен сервере все работает идеально.

```
<?php 
require_once('./phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); //папка phpmailer должна лежать в одной директории с этим файлом (ссылка на скачивание выше)
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name']; //добавляем все нужные переменные
$phone = $_POST['phone']; //добавляем все нужные переменные

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //проще всего делать через gmail. В "Управление аккаунтом Google" выбираем "Безопасность". Почти в самом низу будет "Ненадежные приложения, у которых и т.д." - это мы должны включить!

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'yourEmail@gmail.com'; //реальная gmail почта
$mail->Password = 'yourPass'; //реальный пароль от этой почты
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('yourEmail@gmail.com'); //повторяем ту же gmail почту 
$mail->addAddress('example@yandex.ru'); //куда хотим получать письма (уже не обязательно от гугла)

$mail->isHTML(true); //включаем html разметку в письме  

//это оптионально (необязательно)
$title = "<h1>Новая заявка</h1>"; //заголовок
$date = date("d.m.y H:i"); //дата

//это обязательно
$mail->Subject = 'Заявка от ' .$date; //заголовок письма
$mail->Body = $title. '<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ' .$name. '</p><p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ' .$phone; //"тело" письма, т.к. мы включили html, может теперь красиво оформить его

//проверка на отправку. Можно сделать вывод текста, можно отправить юзера на какую-то страницу
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Ошибка';
} else {
    header('Location: thx.html');
}
?>
```

P.P.S.: если нужна почта для отправки писем именно не от гугла, можете мой исходный код, который был в вопросе, исправить защиту и порт на

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

У меня не сработало, но может Вам поможет)

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'cp1251'; 
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                      //отладка
$mail->isSMTP();                                            
$mail->Host       = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru';                 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
$mail->Username   = 'name@yandex.ru';                   
$mail->Password   = 'PASSWORD';                              
$mail->Port         = 465;
```

Comment: Этот ответ в миллион раз полезнее соседнего. В нем показано, КАК УЗНАТЬ, в чем заключается ошибка, чтобы её ИСПРАВИТЬ. А не классический лепет "ну я что-то пошевелил и заработало" - абсолютно бесполезный для всех остальных.